# change typeof datatable column

Tags: c#, mysql, types, foreach, datatable

I want to change the values of a column in a datatable.
The data table is filled with dates from a mySql database. 
I've made a function to set the Column to "Y" or "N" depending on the date in the datatable.
Then a datagrid is filled with the data in the datatable.

I made de following function:

```
public static DataTable  DatePastYesOrNo(DataTable myDataTabel, string kolomNaam)
    {
        foreach(DataRow rij in myDataTabel.Rows)
        {
                string datum = myDataTabel.Rows[0][kolomNaam].ToString();
                DateTime myDatum = DateTime.Parse(datum);
                if (myDatum > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    rij[kolomNaam] = "Y";
                }
                else
                {
                    rij[kolomNaam] = "N";
                }
        }
        return myDataTabel;
     }
```

To excecute the function:

```
string mijnkolomNaam = "Akkoord";
                HelpFunction.DatePastYesOrNo(sTable, mijnkolomNaam);
```

I'm getting the error "N" or "Y" is not a valid datetime. 
So I think de Type of the field also needs to change but I dont know how.

Comment: You should make a new column, and you should use booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a new bool column and populate it

`DataColumn myBoolCol = myDataTabel.Columns.Add("MyBoolColumn", typeof(bool));`

```
public static DataTable  DatePastYesOrNo(DataTable myDataTabel, string kolomNaam)
{
    foreach(DataRow rij in myDataTabel.Rows)
    {
            string datum = myDataTabel.Rows[0][kolomNaam].ToString();
            DateTime myDatum = DateTime.Parse(datum);
            if (myDatum > DateTime.Now)
            {
                rij["MyBoolColumn"] = "Y";
            }
            else
            {
                rij["MyBoolColumn"] = "N";
            }
    }
    return myDataTabel;
 }
```